# Java - Multiple input using KeyBindings

Tags: java, keyboard, game-engine

I am in the process of making just a small 2 player game, where one player is controlled using WASD and the other is controlled using arrow keys. First I used the **KeyListener** to handle my input but I soon realized that it can't recognize simultaneous inputs. Then I did some researching and found out that **KeyBindings** is a good alternative for simultaneous input. I used the site [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) to figure out how to use this thing and midway I realized that this solution had an issue. The site stated that

> Lets say you have one component you want to control with the arrow keys and another component by using W/A/S/D. This is no problem when using Key Bindings. You just create another MotionWithKeyBindings and assign the bindings for the 4 keys and you are good to go.

which meant that I was required to have 2 different **JComponent** objects assigned to each player. Currently, both my **InputMap** and **ActionMap** are retrieved from a single JPanel which both my players are on. Is the only solution to make both my players into separate **JComponent** objects? If so, how would I go about doing that? Here is my **KeyBindings** code:

```
    public void setKeyBindings(InputMap im, ActionMap am) {
    if (id == 1) {       // id is a unique number granted to players 1 and 2
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "LEFT");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "RIGHT");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "UP");

        am.put("LEFT", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                xVel = -3;
            }
        });

        am.put("RIGHT", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                xVel = 3;
            }
        });

        am.put("UP", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (!jumping) {
                    jumping = true;
                    yVel = -10;
                }
            }
        });

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "LEFT_RELEASED");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "RIGHT_RELEASED");

        am.put("LEFT_RELEASED", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                xVel = 0;
            }
        });

        am.put("RIGHT_RELEASED", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                xVel = 0;
            }
        });

    } 
    if (id == 2) {
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "LEFT_2");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "RIGHT_2");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "UP_2");

        am.put("LEFT_2", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                xVel = -3;
            }
        });

        am.put("RIGHT_2", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                xVel = 3;
            }
        });

        am.put("UP_2", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (!jumping) {
                    jumping = true;
                    yVel = -10;
                }
            }
        });

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "LEFT_RELEASED_2");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "RIGHT_RELEASED_2");

        am.put("LEFT_RELEASED_2", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                xVel = 0;
            }
        });

        am.put("RIGHT_RELEASED_2", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                xVel = 0;
            }
        });
    }
}
```